# Tips to speed up debugging in Codegear

Tags: debugging, c++builder, c++builder-2009

Are there any tips to speed up debugging in Codegear?

For example, when I set breakpoints it can sometimes take a long time for the IDE to be active once the breakpoint is reached and likewise when I hit F8(stepover).

Comment: I'm finding in Builder 2010 that the first step after reaching a breakpoint is slow, after that everything is fast.  I also find that resuming run after a breakpoint is slow.  It must have something to do  with the setup and breakdown that the debugger does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Hesik's Blog mentions one:
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/chrishesik/2009/09/22/34916